# plotly blazor surface plot won't refresh when source data is updated

Tags: plotly, blazor-server-side

I am developing a blazor server side app to display test data in a 3D surface plot using plotly.blazor, and I require the ability to update the plot if the user chooses to display a different data set.  When the page is first created the surface plot renders correctly with the default test data, but when I select a different data set using the combo box the plot comes up two dimensional and blank with the old title (I clear the data before adding a new surface data set and I update the layout with new titles etc).

I have stepped through the code and I know that the new data is all there and correct, but for some reason perhaps the @data-Bind="data" isn't fired?  Yet confusingly it is fired when I use chart.Clear()...

I have tried chart.React(), but it made no difference.  So far the only thing that fixes it is refreshing the page.

**I do not have this problem with a 2D scatter plot.**

Side note: I am relatively new to both blazor and plotly.

Abridged code below:

```
@using Plotly.Blazor
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces
@using Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib
@inject ResultsService resultsService

<PlotlyChart style="height: 100vh; min-height: 600px" @bind-Layout="layout3D_dBV" @bind-Config="config" Data="data" @ref="@cht_dBVvsFvsA" />

@code {

List<decimal> x = new List<decimal> {}; //populated in OnInitializedAsync
List<decimal> y = new List<decimal> {}; //populated in OnInitializedAsync
Layout layout3D_dBV = new Layout();
Config config = new Config();
List<decimal[]> z;
IList<ITrace> data= new List<ITrace>();
string selectedZ = "mV";

private PlotlyChart cht_dBVvsFvsA;

private async Task Replot() //this code fires on button click to update plots
{
    await cht_dBVvsFvsA.Clear();        
    ConfigureLayout();
    data.Clear();
    z.Clear();        
    Get3DplotData();        
}

private void ConfigureLayout()
{        
    layout3D_dBV = new Layout
    {
        Title = new Title
        {
            Text = selectedZ + " vs Amplitude vs Frequency"
        },
        Scene = new[]
                {
        new Scene()
        {
            XAxis = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.XAxis(){Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.XAxisLib.Title(){Text = "Frequency (Hz)"}},
            YAxis = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.YAxis(){Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.YAxisLib.Title(){Text = "Amplitude in (mV)"}},
            ZAxis = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.ZAxis(){Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.ZAxisLib.Title(){Text = "Amplidue out (" + selectedZ + ")"}}
        }
    },
        Margin = new Margin
        {
            L = 65,
            R = 50,
            B = 65,
            T = 90
        }
    };

config = new Config
    {
        Responsive = true
    };
}
private void Get3DplotData()    
{  
    
    z = new List<decimal[]>();        

    for(int i = 0; i < y.Count; i++)
    {
        var currentValues = new List<decimal>();
        
        currentValues = resultsService.GetResults(y[i]);
       
        z.Add(currentValues.ToArray());
    }
    
    data.Add(new Surface()
        {                        
            X = x.Cast<object>().ToList(),
            Y = y.Cast<object>().ToList(),
            Z = z.Cast<object>().ToList()                        
        });
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding these three lines of code to the Replot method:

```
cht_dBVvsFvsA.Layout = layout3D_dBV;        
cht_dBVvsFvsA.Data = data;
cht_dBVvsFvsA.Update();
```